# Unevenly sampled data and the Lomb-Scargle method

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I managed to estimate the periodogram of unevenly sampled data using the [Lomb-Scargle Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis). Analyzing the frequency domain it would be interesting to filter out a frequency band and then apply IFFT and get back a filtered signal (of course this would be evenly sampled and quite different from the original).

The Lomb-Scargle method does not allow for this procedure. Is there a common approach? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well known principle of digital signals, known as "zero padding" applies here, i.e. adding zeros in one domain results in an increased sampling rate in the other domain. This principle also applies if you were to set certain frequency components in the frequency domain to zero.

If we can assume that the Lomb-Scargle periodogram estimate is equivalent to a periodogram estimate obtained from an equivalent evenly sampled signal using an FFT then setting frequency components to zero and applying a IFFT may be a valid approach. Windowing with a Hamming window or equivalent may be an appropriate intermediate step.

A good explanatory link on zero-padding is given [here](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-interpolate-in-time-domain-by-zero-padding-in-frequency-domain)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! In the case of Lomb-Scargle I get an estimate of periodogram only - right? The periodogram is proportional to the squared modulus of the FFT. So there is no unique IFFT. Lomb-Scargle yields something like $k |FFT|^2$ but not $FFT$, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes that's correct but if you assume the signal is real valued, you could take the IFFT of the periodogram square root (this may not hold for all signal properties given non-unique solution)